# How to get Google Speech API's asynchronous speech transcription working for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I'm currently looking into ways to handle long (1-60min) audio file transcription. Google has many samples of how to use its Speech API [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech) but these can only handle audio <1 min in length.

When I do give it audio >1 min, it gives me messages along the lines of:

"Sync input too long. For audio longer than 1 min, use LongRunningRecognize with a 'uri' parameter."

Does anyone have examples of transcribing longer audio files with Google's Speech API? Or perhaps is there a site where the API is described in detail for Swift/Objective-C?